# Mage GetResourceModel in specific language in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module, collection, language

I am working on a module to pull inventory data into a feed. For this we use `Mage::getResourceModel.`

Pulling the data works alright, I just have the problem that the language changes depending on the origin of the requesting client.

How do i pass the right Filter to keep the language in let's say italian?

```
     //get product types
    $productTypes = $this->getProductTypesSQL();
    $productIds =  $this->getProductIds($page, $limit, $productTypes);

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds))
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
```

This code pulls a collection of items alright, however the language is defaulted by the client's location.